# Custom domain name with AWS AppSync using CDK v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I try to add a custom domain name to my AWS AppSync API using the AWS CDK (v2).

First, I manually added a certificate for my domain. I did this in the `us-east-1` region (while my API is hosted in `eu-central-1`) as this seems to be necessary. `APPSYNC_CERT_ARN` refers to this certificate's ARN.

This is the TypeScript code I have in my cdk stack:

```
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as appsync from "@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha";
const APPSYNC_CERT_ARN = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxxx";

export class ApiStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const certificate = cdk.aws_certificatemanager.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(
      this,
      "cert",
      APPSYNC_CERT_ARN,
    );
    const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, "Api", {
      name: "my-api",
      domainName: {
        certificate,
        domainName: "my.domain.com",
      },
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

However, as I add the domainName member, I get the following error during `cdk deploy`:

```
Resource of type 'AWS::AppSync::DomainNameApiAssociation' with identifier 'null' was not found.
```

The feature to add custom AppSync domains via cdk is rather new, so I did not find any hints on what I do wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you followed the full guide at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html#custom-domain-names ? Seems like Route53 setup is missing in your code

Comment: I do not use Route53 service but host the DNS myself. Of course, the DNS entry exists and points to the AWS appsync URL `xxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`. So, do I need something else if Route53 is not used?

Answer (score 3):

In order to create an AppsyncDomainNameApiAssociation (which is the underlying cloudformation resource created by the CDK construct you are using) you have to create both the GraphqlAPI and an AppsyncDomainName prior to creating the association. Although the docs don't really reflect this relationship you can read about ["AWS::AppSync::DomainName" here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-appsync-domainname.html).

Including the "domainName" object in your GraphqlApi instantiation creates the association resources but fails to create the actual domain name resources. You'll need to create it before hand by using the L1 construct for CFNDomainName then manually create the association using the L1 construct CfnDomainNameApiAssociation.

The constructs aren't included in the aws_appsync_alpha library. You'll need to import them from aws_appsync and use them like this:

```
const certificate = cdk.aws_certificatemanager.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(
  this,
  "cert",
  APPSYNC_CERT_ARN,
);Ï

const appsyncDomainName = new aws_appsync.CfnDomainName(
  this,
  'AppsyncDomainName',
  {
    certificateArn: certificate.certificateArn,
    domainName: "my.domain.com",
  }
);


const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, "Api", {
  name: "my-api",
  // Omit the domainName object
  ...
});

const assoc = new aws_appsync.CfnDomainNameApiAssociation(
  this,
  'MyCfnDomainNameApiAssociation',
  {
    apiId: api.apiId,
    domainName: "my.domain.com",
  }
);

//  Required to ensure the resources are created in order
assoc.addDependsOn(appsyncDomainName);
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this could be considered as a temporary work-around until the cdk lib gets fixed/improved?

Comment: Yep, downsides of using an experimental library.

Comment: good news, it looks like the appsync alpha library now handles this with the constructor, so OPs code ought to work

Answer (score 0):

**If you do use Route53:**

Keeping the same code you already have you will need to add a CNAME record:

```
import {
  ARecord,
  CnameRecord,
  HostedZone,
  RecordTarget
} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53'


// Add record
 new CnameRecord(this, `ApiAliasRecord`, {
   recordName: "my.domain.com", // i.e api.foo.com
   zone: HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'Zone', { domainName: "domain.com", }),
   domainName: Fn.select(2, Fn.split('/', api.graphqlUrl))
 })
```

**External DNS:**

Create a CNAME entry with desired api domain name with the value of the internal API domain name (i.e. https://7sdbasdasad8.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)